# Compute shaders - how to globally synchronize threads?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gpgpu, compute-shader

EDIT: I've rephrased the question to make it more general and simplified the code.

I'm probably missing something with thread synchronization in compute shaders. I have a simple compute shader that does parallel reduction on some numbers and then I need to modify the final sum:

```
#version 430 core
#define SIZE 256
#define CLUSTERS 5

layout(local_size_x = 16, local_size_y = 16, local_size_z = 1) in;

struct Cluster {
    vec3 cntr;
    uint size;
};
coherent restrict layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer destBuffer {
    Cluster clusters[CLUSTERS];
};
shared uint sizeCache[SIZE];

void main() {
    const ivec2 pos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    const uint id = pos.y * (gl_WorkGroupSize.x + gl_NumWorkGroups.x) + pos.x;

    if(id < CLUSTERS) {
        clusters[id].size = 0;
    }

    memoryBarrierShared();
    barrier();
    sizeCache[gl_LocalInvocationIndex] = 1;
    int stepv = (SIZE >> 1); 
    while(stepv > 0) { //reduction over data in each working group
        if (gl_LocalInvocationIndex < stepv) {
            sizeCache[gl_LocalInvocationIndex] += sizeCache[gl_LocalInvocationIndex + stepv];
        }
        memoryBarrierShared();
        barrier();
        stepv = (stepv >> 1);
    }
    if (gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0) {
        atomicAdd(clusters[0].size, sizeCache[0]);
    }

    memoryBarrier();
    barrier();

    if(id == 0) {
        clusters[0].size = 23; //this doesn't do what I would expect
        clusters[1].size = 13; //this works
    }
}
```

The *reduction works and produces correct result*. If I comment the last condition, the value in `clusters[0].size` is 262144, which is correct (it is the number of threads). If I uncomment it, I would expect to get value 23, because as I understand it, the threads after `barrier()` should be synchronized and after `memoryBarrier()` all previous changes in memory should be visible. However it doesn't work, it produces result like 259095.I guess that the value 23 is rewritten by previous `atomicAdd` from another thread, but I don't understand why.

This is how I read the result on CPU:

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, resultBuffer);

//currently it dispatches 262144 threads
glDispatchCompute(32, 32, 1);
glCheckError();

glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS); //for debug

struct Cl {
    glm::vec3 cntr;
    uint size;
};

glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, resultBuffer);

std::vector<Cl> data(5);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, sizeOfresult, &data[0]);
```

I have NVIDIA GT630M card and linux with nvidia proprietary driver (331.49).

Comment: You generally need to declare a variable `coherent` for a memory barrier to have any affect on the *visibility* of updates. I would consider declaring the entire definition of `destBuffer` coherent. This will ensure that writes to `ob.clusters []` are respected by your barrier. Otherwise another invocation of this compute shader can easily clobber the value you wrote at the end of the shader in the `if(id == 0)` branch.

Comment: Thanks, I've missed that. However even when I declare the buffer `coherent`, it still produces the same result as before.

Comment: Does anything change if you add `| GL_BUFFER_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT` to your memory barrier in the GL code? I believe the bit you have right now is more for scheduling draw calls that access the SSB, rather than making sure shaders finish before you read the buffer using `glGetBufferSubData (...)`.

Comment: No, I tried even `GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS` for debug and it's still the same. And if I read the original data from the reduction with `glGetBufferSubData`, I always get the correct result.

Comment: The description of `barrier` only claims to synchronize execution within a single work group. I guess `clusters[0]` can be over-written by threads from a group where `id` != 0.

Comment: As has been mentioned a couple of times, it is the fact that you have `if(id == 0)` that is causing problems, as any non 0 id group will be able to write whatever it likes in `clusters[`0 and 1`]` and only group id 0 will trigger the values you want written in there, if yo uwant 23 and 13 to be present in all cases, regardless of what  group is writing, try changing `if(id == 0)` to `if(id == id)` (purely for code preservation whilst testing) or make the 2 lines inside the `if` clause unconditional.

Answer (score 2):

You can't syncronize threads globally, i.e. across work-groups. This is pointed out in the comments by GuyRT. In your code, one workgroup can hit

```
clusters[0].size = 23;
```

while another workgroup is happily doing atomic increments. As it's only the first thread of the first work-group that goes into the `if(id==0)` block and as most GPUs dispatch work-groups in order then the value will be written once and then incremented many times by other (most) work-groups.